# @PropertySource does not bind a String propety to enum automatically?

Tags: spring-boot

In our integration test using springboot 1.4, we used

```
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:test.yml")
```

with the `locations` attribute. This was mapping a string property to enum automatically. But starting from springboot 1.5, the `locations` attribute is removed.

As a workaround, I'm using `@PropertySource` but this doesn't support yaml file. So, I'm using a factory class to convert the yaml to `java.util.properites`. But I'm facing issues, with string property not binding to enum automatically.

Is there any good solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can map **yaml** file to config class

The relative path of **application.yml** file is */myApplication/src/main/resources/application.yml.*

The Spring application takes the first profile as the default profile unless declared otherwise in the Spring application.

**YAML FILE**

```
spring:
    profiles: test
name: test-YAML
environment: test
servers: 
    - www.abc.test.com
    - www.xyz.test.com

---
spring:
    profiles: prod
name: prod-YAML
environment: production
servers: 
    - www.abc.com
    - www.xyz.com
```

**Binding YAML to a Config Class**

To load a set of related properties from a properties file, we will create a bean class:

```
Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
public class YAMLConfig {

    private String name;
    private String environment;
    private List<String> servers = new ArrayList<>();

    // standard getters and setters

}
```

The annotation used here are:

```
@Configuration marks the class as a source of bean definitions
@ConfigurationProperties binds and validates the external configurations to a configuration class
@EnableConfigurationProperties this annotation is used to enable @ConfigurationProperties annotated beans in the Spring application
```

**USAGE:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
 
    @Autowired
    private YAMLConfig myConfig;
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
        app.run();
    }
 
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("using environment: " + myConfig.getEnvironment());
        System.out.println("name: " + myConfig.getName());
        System.out.println("servers: " + myConfig.getServers());
    }
}
```

Comment: @iluvgarden did this help you?